# Get type information about dataclass fields

Tags: python, typing

For a given dataclass, how to get infos about fields type ?

Example:

```
>>> from dataclasses import dataclass, fields
>>> import typing
>>> @dataclass
... class Foo:
...     bar: typing.List[int]
```

I can have fields info with the repr:

```
>>> fields(Foo)
(Field(name='bar',type=typing.List[int],default=<dataclasses._MISSING_TYPE object at 0x7fef9aafd9b0>,default_factory=<dataclasses._MISSING_TYPE object at 0x7fef9aafd9b0>,init=True,repr=True,hash=None,compare=True,metadata=mappingproxy({}),_field_type=_FIELD),)
```

I can have a type repr of my bar field

```
>>> fields(Foo)[0].type
typing.List[int]
```

How to retrieve (as python objects, not as string repr):

- the type (`typing.List`)
- type type of items in the `typing.List` (`int`)

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`type` property of a data class field it's not a string representation, it's a type.

Python 3.6:

```
>>> type(fields(Foo)[0].type)
<class 'typing.GenericMeta'>
```

Python 3.7:

```py
>>> type(fields(Foo)[0].type)
<class 'typing._GenericAlias'>
```

In this case you can retrieve inner type with `__args__` property:

```py
>>> fields(Foo)[0].type.__args__
(<class 'int'>,)
```